# how to use ordinary function with boost::bind

Tags: c++

I have a two vectors. I would like to copy first vector elements to another with some transformation, something like this:

```
void Append(std::string& a, const std::string& b)
{
    a.append(b);
}      


std::vector<std::string> v1;
std::vector<std::string> v2;
...
std::transform (v1.begin(), v1.end(), v2.begin(), 
                 boost::bind(Append, std::string("b")));
```

How can I do this?

Comment: std::bind in the c++11 standard works just like boost::bind, I'd recommend it.

Comment: @Theolodis You mean "just like `boost::bind`".

Comment: @iavr you are right, my bad.

Comment: I would use a lambda rather than bind. But then I would rather use a range-based `for` loop instead of an algorithm thingy. I find the named algorithm readability to be on a par with COBOL, much easier to grok a loop at a glance.

Answer (score 0):

What you are searching is probably this:

```
std::transform (v1.begin(), v1.end(), v2.begin(), 
             std::bind(Append, std::placeholders::_1, std::string("b")));
```

It would call Append with each element of v1, append `"b"` and put it into v2. If you would like to have Append as object method, `std::bind(Class::Append, obj, std::placeholders::_1, std::string("b")));` will be your friend, with the following code:

```
class SomeClass{
public:
    Append(std::string, const std::string);
}
```

Other class:

```
obj = new SomeClass();
std::transform (v1.begin(), v1.end(), v2.begin(), 
             std::bind(Class::Append, obj, std::placeholders::_1, std::string("b")));
```

that way the method of the object obj is bound, not the static class function.

if you want to use boost instead of standard c++:

```
boost::bind(Class::Append, obj, _1, std::string("b"))
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd do something like this (off the cuff):

```
for( string& s : v1 )
{
    s.append( "b" );
}
v2 = v1;
```

Easier to write, easier to understand, easier for compiler to optimize, no need for SO question.

Comment: this is *not* iterating over two vectors.

Comment: If this solution is wrong, it's not in the way Alex meant, I think. It is wrong in that `v1` is now modified, whereas in the original code it was not. This can be easily corrected by reversing the sequence of operations: `v2 = v1; for (string& s: v2) s.append("b");`.

Comment: @iavr: since the OP passed the argument by reference to non-`const`, and return `void`, i thought the most likely intention was modifying. The code here is easy to modify to yield any other desired behavior.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf I didn't downvote. my point being: If the append is a non constant value (unlike here) `std::transform` is necessary or *at least* an iterator-increment of the second vector in the loop-body.

Comment: @Alex: can't say i understand your point, sorry. what does it even mean that "append is a non-constant value"? as i see it this is very very trivial stuff, and my failure to grok your point or assign any meaning to the statement indicates to me that it isn't a point.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf case 1) the reader didn't mean to have a second argument, and the initial code is just weird. case 2) the reader wanted to have a variable argument (and reason to use it). then it sould be something like `auto b = v2.cbegin(); /* up front */` and `s.append(b++);` case 3) the user wanted is having a valid reason to use bind and algorithms and this example is just simplified (and a bad example). In case 1) this is a very fine and valid solution.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf anyway I don't think this is worth such a major discussion. I just wanted to point out that `std::transform` uses two iterators, whereas your example doesn't. Whether it is the right thing or not is up to the OP.